# MySQL get difference between two string fields

Tags: mysql, sql

All,
 I have a mySQL table with two fields, `old` and `new`. Each contain a string in the following format:

`key1=value1, key2=value2, key3=value3`

The keys used in each field for a row are the same, the values may change. For each row, the keys may differ.

Is it possible to have two further columns which compare the values in `old` and `new` and only outputs those key/value pairs which differ?

```
old                          | new                          | diff_old          | diff_new
key1=xxx, key2=yyy, key3=zzz | key1=xxx, key2=aaa, key3=zzz | key2=yyy          | key2=aaa
keya=xxx, keyb=yyy, keyc=zzz | keya=111, keyb=yyy, keyc=222 | keya=xxx, keyc=zzz| keya=111, keyc=222
```

Im aware `SUBSTRING_INDEX` can be used to split strings, however the issue is the differing key/value pairs between rows, meaning a function cant be cooked in so easily.

Comment: The string component of this makes it significantly more challenging...any will to normalize the values in there (so key1, key2, and key3 are seperate fields)?  A combination of substring and charindex to pick out the value for each key and then compare what it picks out is very possible, it's just not that fun to write...a lot of trial and error.

Comment: Is the list of possible keys known and static? Are you looking for something like a MySQL implementation of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem ? Is this a one-off task, or do you want the `diff_old` and `diff_new` columns to be populated as new rows are added to this table?

Answer (score 0):

Used the below query , It gives you the accurate result . I double check my results:

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `try` (
  `old` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `new` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `old_diff` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `new_diff` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(IF(aa.first_string!=aa.first_string1,first_string,''),
IF(aa.middle_string!=aa.middle_string1,middle_string,'') ,
IF(aa.last_string!=aa.last_string1,last_string,'') ) AS first_result, 
CONCAT(IF(aa.first_string!=aa.first_string1,first_string1,''), 
IF(aa.middle_string!=aa.middle_string1,middle_string1,'') ,
IF(aa.last_string!=aa.last_string1,last_string1,'') ) AS second_result
FROM (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`old`, ',', 1), ',', -1) 
AS first_string,   
IF(  LENGTH(`old`) - LENGTH(REPLACE(`old`, ',', ''))>1, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`old`, ',', 2), ',', -1) ,NULL) AS middle_string,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`old`, ',', 3), ',', -1) AS last_string,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`new`, ',', 1), ',', -1) AS first_string1,
IF(  LENGTH(`old`) - LENGTH(REPLACE(`new`, ',', ''))>1, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`new`, ',', 2), ',', -1) ,NULL) AS middle_string1,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`new`, ',', 3), ',', -1) AS last_string1 
FROM try ) aa
```